# Searching through triangle

Tags: python, performance, pascals-triangle

I tried to search for shortest path in Pascal-like triangle with particular "weight" at every point. It looks like this:

```
  2
 3 1
1 4 5
```

eg. in this case, the shortest way is 2->3->1 with total "weight" 6. You are only allowed to (looking from up to down) move to the point that is located one level down to the right or left side of current point. Thus I made solution for this problem it's quite impossible to compute very big inputs like triangle with 100 levels. So I tried to re-write whole algorithm basing on stuff I found across the internet but good only in 50% - I know the "weight" of shortest path but don't know the points that are included. Any ideas?

```
def minSumPath(A): 

    memo = [None] * len(A) 
    n = len(A) - 1

    for i in range(len(A[n])):  
    memo[i] = A[n][i]  


    for i in range(len(A) - 2, -1,-1):  
        for j in range( len(A[i])):  
            memo[j] = A[i][j] + min(memo[j], 
                                    memo[j + 1]);


    return memo[0]
```

EDIT
Particular points(numbers) are stored in list of lists. In eg above it looks like: [[2],[3,1],[1,4,5]]

Comment: Can you please provide the metric used to define distances (eg. how is it related to weights)? Note that for such problems, using the [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm is generally a good approach. But, I am not sure it makes sense here (or if this is the most efficient approach).

Comment: Already edited, number defines weight of that point itself, there are no costs for distance between points but we are only allowed to move 1 level below and on the right or left side of current point :)